# Angular testing simulate ng-click in Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have 1 button in html, for testing i need to simulate the click event in 
jasmine test case , 
here is the html

```
<button id="test" ng-click="getv(12)" >abcd</button>
```

**Test case**

```
 $("#test").trigger('click'); // Not working
 $("#test").click().trigger('click') ; // Not working
 expect(scope.val).toEqual(12);
```

testing framework is jasmine

Comment: Maybe simple typo but the id is `test1` and  you run your trigger on `test`

Comment: i tried with test also, if i change id to anything else its not giving any error

Comment: I think that you should test the function directly and not if the function gets call when a click is triggered. For this is better e2e and you can use protractor: `scope.getcv(12); expect(scope.val).toEqual(12)`

Comment: Actually this is for testing 1 custom num pad and i dont want to use potractor

Comment: try $rootScope.broadcast('click');